# How to apply find_by to elements of an array of arrays - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following array of arrays of `user_ids`:

```
@host_and_guest = [
  ["1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8", "346b5c2f-a459-4c4f-8193-e0928c86c66c"],
  ["1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8", "346b5c2f-a459-4c4f-8193-e0928c86c66c"],
  ["1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8", "346b5c2f-a459-4c4f-8193-e0928c86c66c"],
  ["1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8", "1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8"]
]
```

and I would like to apply `User.find_by(id: XXXX).pluck(:longitude, :latitude,:city)` to each of the `user_id` in order to create a another array of longitude, latitude, and city for each of the sub-array.

Is there an efficient way to do so please ?

Comment: Maybe `User.find(@host_and_guest.flatten)` or `User.where(:id => @host_and_guest.flatten)`

Comment: @Fabio let me try in that direction but it might add further steps to build back the array later on, no ?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, any reason why you rated my question down ?

Comment: Wasn't me. I see no problem with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users = User.where(id: @host_and_guest.flatten)
            .pluck(:id, :longitude, :latitude, :city)
            .group_by(&:first) # creates hash with id as keys

@host_and_guest.map do |pair|
  # replace pair with array of 
  # [[longitude, latitude, city], [longitude, latitude, city]]
  pair.map { |id| users[id]&.drop(1) }
end
```

Comment: This code really just has bad design written all over it though - instead of an array you should be using higher level data structures or better data modeling in the DB.

Comment: Hey, Iadding the drop(1) at the end returns empty arrays to me. I took it off but found myself with a lot of double brackets. Thank you, as it gets me certainly closer to the goal. thank you.